# Use xamarin to build a cross-platform library usable in native apps

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I want to build an iOS native apps and an Android native apps.
I want to keep the code that manage the views purely native, ie. write Java code for Android and Objective-C code for iOS.

I would like to know if it is possible to build a library in C#, using Xamarin (or another tool/technology) ; with models, network code, behavior logic (ViewModel stuff), etc. that could be shared between the 2 native apps. If yes, how ? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it is not supported yet according to [this forum discussion](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2136/is-it-possible-to-call-xamarin-code-from-an-androidiphonewp7-native-app).